# Is it possible to determine what position in a resultset you are from a cursor in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cursor

If I have a Cursor object for a query, is there any way of knowing how far through the resultset I am or do I need to maintain a counter myself?

If it matters, I'm using the Java implementation of GAE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Cursors bookmark a location in a result set - the position between keys - not an offset.